# Best strategy to set dependencies from within unit tests?

Tags: java, unit-testing

Assume a class `Foo`, with a dependency `Bar` which is injected by some DI-Framework (CDI in this case):

```
public class Foo {

   @Inject
   private Bar bar;
   ...
   public void someLogic() {
      ...
   }

}
```

Let - for the sake of the example - `Bar` be a mockable infrastructural dependency, like an `EntityManager` or a `UserTransaction`, which is *out of the scope* of the unit test, but - again for the sake of the example - be required for Foo to be initialized properly.

Assume a **unit test** `FooTest` (I explicitly want to write unit tests *without container dependencies*), that needs to set or mock the dependency somehow, but otherwise tries to keep a low profile in terms of required container functionality (hence not an integration test).

```
public class FooTest {

   private Foo foo;

   @BeforeClass
   public void initFoo() {
      ... set bar somehow ...
   }

   @Test
   public doSomeTestOnSomeMethod() {
      ...
   }

}
```

I'm trying to collect some facts of what's the best strategy in order to set these otherwise container-controlled dependencies from within my test:

(1) Add `getBar()` and `setBar()` to `Foo`

*(-) unnecessary, bloated code(?)
(+) straightforward
(+) works in and for all (test-)classes*

(2) Use reflection to set `bar`

*(-) complicated, harder to read & maintain
(+) works in and for all (test-)classes*

(3) Remove `private` qualifier to make those fields accessible from within the test (assuming same package)

*(+) Easiest and shortest solution
(-) Not the smallest scope in terms of production code
(-) Not usable outside of the package*

Is there any clear advice on this topic?

**Update:** I'm aware that I can use the container as a dependency provider for tests - I do this for integration tests, but I certainly don't want the full Java EE stack in a unit test. 
I hope this does not lead to a flamewar on frameworks ;-)

**Update2:** Thanks everyone for answering so far, but I seem to have expressed myself unclear. The answers tend to indicate that I don't make enough use of the possibilities of the underlaying DI-framework, or simply need more mocking. That's certainly all good and true, but I rather wanted to collect opinions on  whether it's okay to extend a class member's visibility to default level in order to leverage testibility, if the "test-exclusive"-getter-setter approach is better, or if reflection (my current solution) is the way to go. Tried to edit the question so that it better describes my problem.

**Resume and closing** If I had the appropriate rights I would very much like to close this question, because I obviously expressed myself in a very misleading and somehow confusing way. I was neither looking for a discussion about correct dependency injection in tests, nor did I want any code snippets. My - gloriously failed - intention was to start a discussion on what I already wrote in Update 2. Thanks to everyone who contributed - I will certainly put more effort in future questions.

Comment: This is a classic problem, which is anything but localised, to which Sam Holder has even supplied a correct answer, so it's a shame this was closed. Oh well.

Comment: Well, it was closed because the author asked for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a setter to the class being tested and in the unit test, inject [a mock version](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object) of the `Bar` class. Mockito, EasyMock, JMock all make this dead simple.

Without a setter on the `Foo` class, how can anyone use it outside of your container anyway? Labeling a setter as "bloat" sounds overblown to me. I believe you are overthinking the situation.

An update for your update:

> That's certainly all good and true, but I rather wanted to collect opinions on whether it's okay to extend a class member's visibility to default level in order to leverage testibility, of if the getter-setter approach is better, or if reflection (my current solution) is the way to go.

My personal opinion is that adding a setter is just a few additional keystrokes (which most IDEs will automate for you), whereas changing the visibility of the fields can lead to other poor choices down the road (suddenly someone decides they can write production code that uses the field directly as well, since you didn't make it `private`), and using reflection requires more code (and is slower) than simply using the setter. A `setBar(Bar)` method is about as simple as it gets.

Comment: Hm, I might have reduced the complexity of the example too much and maybe expressed myself a bit unclear - I feel it all goes a bit in a  wrong direction ;-) Imagine Bar as an EntityManager - certainly noone would want to use it directly.

Comment: I meant `Foo` is not very usable directly without any ability to pass in it's dependencies other than the reflection magic that the DI container performs on the `@Autowired` field.

Comment: thanks for answering, I tried to rephrase the question to reflect my question better. BTW, same magic but no `@Autowired` in CDI

Comment: @Autowired, @Inject, same thing :)

Answer (score 3):

I think you should be changing the code so that this dependency is declared through the constructor, and have the DI framework inject it there, then in your test you just pass the mock.

Having it the way it currently is makes the dependency on this thing 'hidden', there is no way for the consuming code to know that a `Bar` is required and this makes the code confusing and difficult to understand.

It also means you are dependent on the DI framework, rather then having the ability to construct your object graph manually if you want to.  It also looks like this might make it difficult to change DI frameworks if you wanted to

Answer (score 2):

I would use your DI injection framework to create Foo and initialize bar.  This is how you intend to use it.

---

You can also set it without changing the code with reflections.

```
public static void set(Object o, String field, Object value) {
    for (Class c = o.getClass(); c != null; c = c.getSuperclass())
        try {
            Field f = c.getDeclaredField(field);
            f.setAccessible(true);
            f.set(o, value);
            return;
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException ignored) {
            if (c == Object.class)
                throw new AssertionError(e);
            continue;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new AssertionError(e);
        }
}

Foo foo = new Foo();
set(foo, "bar", new Bar());
```

---

Rather than making the field public or widely accessible, you could make the field protected and set it via a subclass.

```
 public class Foo {
     protected Bar bar;
 }

 // in the test
 Foo foo = new Foo() {{
     bar = new Bar();
 }};
 // test the foo
```

This way the original class doesn't give away too much but you can test its functionality through a sub class.

Comment: I would certainly do this for (some) integration tests, but for a (lean) unit test, I want to test without having dependencies to a full blown JEE application server...

Comment: There must be a way to do DI without running a JEE server.

Comment: Yes, you simply ... pass the dependency to the object. With a setter or via a constructor.

Comment: I mean using the existing framework.  You can use reflections to set the fields.

Comment: @Pete - thanks for answering. I tried to rephrase my question to make my problem / the desired discussion more clear. I'm currently using the reflection approach, but am discussing with a colleague who favors changing the visibility modifier - something I strongly disagree with.

Comment: That is another option.  The field is effectively public from the DI's point of view.  You may find making the field package-private is a better compromise provided you can make the test in the same package.  Another option is to make the field protected and test a derived class.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you don't want to import all the Java EE stack in your test, but if you want to test components injecting others components you should probably make some compromise to have a light CDI layer in you test.

The best solution for that is using [Arquillian](http://www.jboss.org/arquillian) with a light CDI container like *arquillian-weld-ee-embedded-1.1*. With CDI you'll also use [@Alternative](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/1.1.0.Final/en-US/html/injection.html#alternatives) to provide a mocked version of your beans. With Arquillian you test will look like that :

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class FooTest {
    @Inject
    Foo myFoo;


    @Deployment
    public static Archive<?> createTestArchive() throws FileNotFoundException {
        File beanFile = new File("src/test/resources/META-INF/beans.xml");
        if (!beanFile.exists())
            throw new FileNotFoundException();
        Archive<?> ret = ShrinkWrap
                .create(WebArchive.class, "test.war")
                .addClasses(Foo.class, FooImpl.class);
        return ret;
    }



    @Test
    public void testFoo() {
        // Do the test with Foo
    }
}
```

The @Deployment static method create a pseudo deployment of your project to enable the CDI container. You decide the type of container in your Maven file like

```
<profile>
        <id>weld-ee-embedded-1.1</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>arquillian</name>
                <value>weld-ee-embedded</value>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
                <artifactId>arquillian-weld-ee-embedded-1.1</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0.Alpha5</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.weld</groupId>
                <artifactId>weld-core</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.weld</groupId>
                <artifactId>weld-api</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <dependencyManagement>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.weld</groupId>
                    <artifactId>weld-core-bom</artifactId>
                    <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
                    <type>pom</type>
                    <scope>import</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </dependencyManagement>
    </profile>
```

Your test won't be integration test since you'll wrap only what you need and mock the other components with @Alternatives but you'll have a real CDI component with it's container and lifecycle to play with.

Comment: Thanks for making this point. I'm aware of the Arquillian project, and am definitely willing to use it. As Arquillian will always start a appserver (embedded or not), I still call this integration test (but certainly don't want to argue about words here) ;-) I also know from my own experience that wrapping all dependencies into a deployment will get extremely unpleasant quite soon after the HelloWorld-example, which is another reason why I consider Arquillian to be oversized for a simple unit test - but again, it's definitely the future of enterprise testing...